# Tools for JavaScript-based image manipulation?

Tags: javascript, image-editor, jpg

I need to implement photo editing capability into a website, and only JavaScript-based solutions are allowed (no Flash, sorry). The editor should not require local nor remote database, nor should it require connection to a third party servers. In other words, the editor has to be usable inside a local Web app. Also, the editor should support editing of JPG, PNG, and GIF images, so only SVG support (such as in svg-edit) is not enough.

I was able to find several online image editing tools, but most of them were either not embeddable or use Flash. The best I could find were [Picozu](https://www.picozu.com) and [Photopea](http://www.photopea.com/), although I'm not sure how much their licenses allow modifications to the code. I also found DarkroomJS and CamanJS, but these seem to be lacking many basic features.

Did I miss something, or are these the only tools available for JavaScript-based image manipulation? What open source JavaScript libraries could I use if I wanted to implement own editor GUI?

Comment: *nor should it require connection to a third party servers*. So a call from your web page pulling in a Javascript library from a third party is not allowed?